# Expiring Dictionaries with individual TTLs

Tags: python, dictionary

I need a dictionary where I can store items with a TTL (time to live) so that the items disappear once the time is up. I found the ExpiringDict class for this purpose but it appears to be restricted to having the same timeout for each item in the dictionary. Is there an alternative that lets me specify different timeout values for each key?

Comment: Do either of these answers [address your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)?

Answer (score 1):

It is easy to build yourself. Ingredients: a normal `dict` to store the values; a `heapq` to store `(expiry, key)` pairs; a `Thread` to run a loop, check the top of the heap and delete (or mark expired, depending on what your need is) while top's expiry is in the past (don't forget to let it sleep). When you push to `dict`, at the same time add `(now + ttl, key)` to the `heapq`. There's some details that you might want to attend to (e.g. removing stuff from `heapq` if you delete from `dict` etc, though that'd be a bit slow as you'd have to search the heap, then re-heapify - again, only necessary if your use case requires it) but the basic idea is quite simple.

Answer (score 0):

One place to look for inspiration might be Django's [`LocMemCache`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/cache/#local-memory-caching) in-memory key-value object.  It basically wraps a `_cache` dict to hold the actual cache and an `_expire_info` dict to store any expiry.  Then in `get()`, it will call `self._has_expired()` and make the comparison to the current timestamp with `time.time()`.

You can find the class at [`django.core.cache.backends.locmem`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/cache/backends/locmem.py).

Granted, this is not a dict subclass; as mentioned above, it actually wraps two separate dictionaries, one for caching and one for storing expiries; but, its API is dictionary-like.